# AmpScript: How do I get values from dynamic variables in a loop?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

Here is a simplified example: I have some values set for multiple products in an email:

```
set @product1 = "Name of product one"
set @product1link = "URL for product 1"
set @product2 = "Name of product two"
set @product2link = "URL for product 2" 
set @product3 = "Name of product three"
set @product3link = "URL for product 3" 
set @product4 = "Name of product four"
set @product4link = "URL for product 4"
```

The loop picks up each product:

```
%%[
set @myCount = 0
set @totalProducts = 4
]%%
%%[ FOR @myCount = 1 TO @totalProducts DO ]%%
        %%[
        set @productTitle = Concat("@product",@myCount)
        ]%%
            <h1>%%=v(@productTitle)=%%</h1> 
%%[ NEXT ]%%
```

What I expected to get would be:

```
Name of product one
Name of product two
Name of product three
Name of product four
```

The output I get is:

```
@product1
@product2
@product3
@product4
```

How can I set `@productTitle` so that it will get the value set for each product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    %%[
        Set @product1 = "Name of product one"
        Set @product1link = "URL for product 1"
        Set @product2 = "Name of product two"
        Set @product2link = "URL for product 2" 
        Set @product3 = "Name of product three"
        Set @product3link = "URL for product 3" 
        Set @product4 = "Name of product four"
        Set @product4link = "URL for product 4"

        Set @myCount = 0
        Set @totalProducts = 4

        For @myCount = 1 To @totalProducts Do
            Set @declaredValue = Concat('%%=v(@product',@myCount,')=%%')
    ]%%
        %%=TreatAsContent(@declaredValue)=%%<br>
    %%[
        Next @myCount 
    ]%%
```

This produced an output of:

Name of product one
Name of product two
Name of product three
Name of product four

Comment: Thanks.  Nice shot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your original code was nearly there, just remove the ""s when you concat @product, otherwise it will be treated as a string:

```
%%[
set @myCount = 0
set @totalProducts = 4
]%%
%%[ FOR @myCount = 1 TO @totalProducts DO ]%%
       %%[
        set @productTitle = Concat(@product,@myCount)
        ]%%
            <h1>%%=v(@productTitle)=%%</h1> 

%%[ NEXT ]%%
```